# Discord.py Showing User Badges

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to do a command that shows a user's badges. This is my code:

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def test(ctx, user: discord.Member):
        test = discord.Embed(title=f"{user.name} User's Badges", description=f"{user.public_flags}", color=0xff0000 )
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=test)
```

And the bot is responding like this

```
<PublicUserFlags value=64>
```

I want it to respond like this

```
Hype Squad ...
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could do `str(user.public_flags.all())` to obtain a string value of all the badges an user has. Although this is an improvement, your output will still be something like: `[<UserFlags.hypesquad_brilliance: 128>]`. But the advantage here is that the words `hypesquad` and `brilliance` are clearly indicated in the string. Now, all you have to do is to remove `[<UserFlags.`, `_` and `: 128>]` from the string.

Here is a way to re-define your code:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def test(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    # Remove unnecessary characters
    hypesquad_class = str(user.public_flags.all()).replace('[<UserFlags.', '').replace('>]', '').replace('_',
                                                                                                         ' ').replace(
        ':', '').title()

    # Remove digits from string
    hypesquad_class = ''.join([i for i in hypesquad_class if not i.isdigit()])

    # Output
    test = discord.Embed(title=f"{user.name} User's Badges", description=f"{hypesquad_class}", color=0xff0000)
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=test)
```

Answer (score 0):

`user.public_flags` is not the way to access the user's profile.

From the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=profile#discord.Profile), you need to use `user.profile()` to get attributes like *premium*,
*staff*, *hypesquad*.

Since discord.py 1.7 it is impossible to get info from the [user's profile](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=profile#discord.Profile) using `await user.profile()`. In the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=profile#discord.Profile) it states that this functionality is *deprecated*. If you try it you get an error `Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 20001): Bots cannot use this endpoint`

Answer (score 0):

Here a little correction from the code from [@GGBerry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14523948/ggberry)

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def test(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    userFlags = user.public_flags.all()
    for flag in userFlags:
        print(flag.name)
```

`user.public_flags.all()` returns a list, that can be iterated. In the list are flag object from the type discord.UserFlag. This object contains all sorts of badges. Here is the documentation for the UserFlags: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=userflag#discord.UserFlags